# How does TypeScript infer its generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a two part question here. The first is a straightforward specific technical clarification. The second is that I have inconsistent behaviour between my VSCode and TypeScript and I want to know what setting is causing it.

### 1. Which property does/should TypeScript use to determine the generic parameter?

I have a type that makes multiple references to a generic parameter T like:

```js
type SomeComponentProps<T> = {
  onChange: (value: T) => void; 
  availableValues: Array<T>; 
  selectedValue: T | null; 
  generateString: (value: T) => string; 
}
```

And I use this type like:

```
SomeComponent({
  onChange: (value: Foo | null | string | number) => {}, // Note all the typings here.
  availableValues: foos,
  selectedValue: null,
  generateString: (v) => v.a //(parameter) v: Foo
})
```

[TypeScript Playground 4.9.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#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)

In this playground the type of `v` is 'Foo'. TypeScript has decided that the generic parameter `T` is type `Foo`. Question is - how is TypeScript determining that it is `Foo` and not `Foo | null | string | number`?

Property ordering, either in the type declaration, or in the use of the function do not appear to change how the type is inferred. What else is it? A union of the possible types?

Note that changing the onChange property from an arrow function to a regular function changes the behaviour of inference:

```
SomeComponent({
  //Changed this to a regular function
  onChange: function (value: Foo | null | string | number) {},
  availableValues: foos,
  selectedValue: null,
  generateString: (v) => v.a //Property 'a' does not exist on type 'string | number | Foo'.
                                //Property 'a' does not exist on type 'string'.
})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5&ssl=36&ssc=3&pln=30&pc=1#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-wWkA)

### 2. Inconsistent behaviour in between TypeScript Playground and VSCode

I have copy pasted the above code into a `testFile.ts` and a `testFile.tsx`. I have manually set the TypeScript version t. 4.9.5. In both cases the parameter v has the the type `Foo | null | string | number` - what is likely causing this? One of the compiler options perhaps?

**Runnable Repro**

I have been able to reproduce this issue here: https://github.com/dwjohnston/typescript-type-inference-thingy This is essentially a basic `tsc --init` using TypeScript `4.9.5`.

It seems like the `strict: false` flag changes how this inference happens. Curiously enough though, this behaviour does not occur in TypeScript playground.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in your section\#2 locally with no tsconfig.json. Provide a [mre] (emphasis on "reproducible").

Comment: @user See my update. I have managed to create a repro as a github repo.

Comment: See the section of [ask] on why external repros are not preferred.

Comment: Could you [edit] this so that there is only one question (or at least one very clearly *primary* question whose answer suffices to address the issue fully)?  Otherwise it is likely to be closed with the reason "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Comment: @jcalz It feels like a pretty clear kind of question, even if I've phrased it as two questions. Essentially 'how is the inference determined, and what configurations change it?'

Comment: Could you come up with a way to phrase it as a single question that doesn't include that "and" clause in there?  Or at least make it clear that answering the first is of primary importance and the second one is a "nice to have" but isn't required?  I'm having a hard time seeing this as a single question as it currently is.  Anyway, I won't leave another comment about this, since I don't want to derail things any further.

Comment: @YetAnotherFrank weird. I just checked both and they're behaving as I've described in the corresponding code block.

Comment: Never mind, I mixed up your two Playground links. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

> Question is - how is TypeScript determining that it is Foo and not Foo | null | string | number?

The problem is that you define `onChange` as follows:

```
onChange: (value: T) => void;
```

But later on you supply it with an arrow function like this:

```
onChange: (value: Foo | null | string | number) => "hello!"
```

Note that `onChange` should be a function that returns `void` but your arrow function returns `string`. If you use a regular anonymous function like this:

```
onChange: function(value: Foo | null | string | number) {return;}
```

...TypeScript will infer `Foo | null | string | number`  as [you expect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#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):

[image]

### UPDATE (to answer question from comment)

> Using an anonymous function does. But the question still remains, why *does* using an regular anonymous function change the behaviour of the inference compare to an arrow anonymous function ?

**The Lord works in mysterious ways...and apparently so does TypeScript**. It turns out, if you use a regular anonymous function that is assigned to a variable, the behaviour changes again, this time it infers `Foo` just like it did with an arrow function:

```
const fun2 = function(value: Foo | null | string | number) { return; }

SomeComponent({
  onChange: fun2, // <-- anonymous function assigned via a variable. Infers Foo.
  availableValues: foos, 
  selectedValue: null,   
  generateString: (v) => v.a //(parameter) v: Foo
})
```

I honestly wouldn't stress too much about this because the TypeScript team admits that they sometimes get these things wrong. To quote the pull request on [Higher order function type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) which covers some of the logic at play here (emphasis is mine):

> The above algorithm is not a complete unification algorithm and **it is by no means perfect**. In particular, it only delivers the desired outcome **when types flow from left to right**. However, this has **always been the case for type argument inference in TypeScript**, and it has the highly desired attribute of working well as code is being typed.

From the above we can at least know for sure that type inference works in a left-to-right manner, but beyond that, I reckon only the TypeScript team can explain the difference in behaviour between inline anonymous functions, arrow functions and a variable that's been assigned an anonymous function.

So in summary: TypeScript does work in mysterious ways...but occasionally, mysterious things like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) lead to really cool things like [--strictBindCallApply](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency in the typing. Although note that: that I am returning a string doesn't actually change the behaviour. Using an anonymous function _does_. But the question still remains, why does using an regular anonymous function change the behaviour of the inference compare to an  arrow anonymous function ?

Comment: I will update my question to remove the string return, as not to confuse things. I'll also include the comparison between arrow functions and regular functions.

Comment: @dwjohnston I updated the answer to include links to official source material that can help further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

1. TypeScript infers the generic parameter T in the type SomeComponentProps based on the type of the value passed in for the availableValues property. In your example, foos is an array of type Foo[], so TypeScript infers that T is the same as Foo. This is because the Array type in the SomeComponentProps type definition requires that the availableValues property is an array of the same type as T.
   The type of v in the generateString function is inferred based on the type of the selectedValue property, which is of type T | null. Since you passed null as the value for selectedValue, TypeScript infers that T must be Foo | null.
2. The behavior you're seeing in VSCode is likely due to the version of TypeScript being used by VSCode, which may be different from the version you're using in the TypeScript Playground. You can check the version of TypeScript being used by VSCode by opening the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows or Linux, Cmd+Shift+P on macOS) and searching for "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version". This will show you the version of TypeScript that VSCode is currently using.
   If you want to use the same version of TypeScript in VSCode as you're using in the TypeScript Playground, you can configure VSCode to use a specific version of TypeScript by adding a tsconfig.json file to your project and specifying the version of TypeScript you want to use in the compilerOptions section. For example, to use TypeScript version 4.9.5, you could add the following to your tsconfig.json file:

   {
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "strict": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "skipLibCheck": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "noEmit": true,
   "isolatedModules": true,
   "types": [],
   "lib": ["es6"],
   "types": ["node"],
   "typescript": "4.9.5"
   },
   "include": ["src/**/*"]
   }

This will tell VSCode to use TypeScript version 4.9.5 when compiling your project.

The reason for the difference in behavior between the arrow function and the regular function in your example has to do with how TypeScript infers the type of the onChange property in the SomeComponent function call.

When you use an arrow function, TypeScript infers the type of the onChange property as a union type of all the possible types of the arrow function parameters. In your case, the arrow function has a parameter of type Foo | null | string | number, so TypeScript infers the type of the onChange property as ((value: Foo | null | string | number) => void).

On the other hand, when you use a regular function, TypeScript infers the type of the onChange property as the type of the function itself. In your case, the type of the function is (value: Foo | null | string | number) => void, so TypeScript infers the type of the onChange property as (value: Foo | null | string | number) => void.

The difference in behavior between the two is due to the fact that arrow functions have a more complex syntax that allows them to represent multiple types of functions, including functions with optional or rest parameters. This makes it more difficult for TypeScript to infer the type of the arrow function, and so it falls back to inferring the union type of all the possible parameter types.

In contrast, regular functions have a simpler syntax that only allows them to represent a single type of function, so TypeScript can more easily infer the type of the function.

The strict compiler option in TypeScript enables a set of strict type-checking options, including --strictNullChecks, which is responsible for the difference in behavior you're seeing between strict and non-strict mode.

In non-strict mode, TypeScript allows null and undefined to be assignable to any type, which means that the type of the selectedValue property in your example is inferred as T | null, where T is inferred as Foo. This means that the type of the generateString function is inferred as (value: Foo | null) => string.

However, in strict mode, TypeScript enforces stricter type checking rules, including the --strictNullChecks option, which prevents null and undefined from being assignable to non-nullable types. This means that the type of the selectedValue property is inferred as T, where T is inferred as Foo | null. This means that the type of the generateString function is inferred as (value: Foo | null) => string in non-strict mode and as (value: Foo) => string in strict mode.

The reason for the difference in behavior between VSCode and the TypeScript Playground may be due to differences in the versions of TypeScript being used or in the configuration of the TypeScript environment. It's possible that the TypeScript Playground is using a different version of TypeScript or a different configuration than your local environment, which could be causing the difference in behavior.

Comment: 1. Why does a regular function change the behaviour of inference, as opposed an arrow function? 2. Why does the the `strict` compiler option change the behaviour of the inference? (Although, note that this behaviour is observable in VSCode only,  not in TypeScript playground).

Comment: If you check out the repro I have linked - I'm using 4.9.5.

Comment: I have updated the original answer to address your questions

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the some references to some of the claims made? eg "When you use an arrow function, TypeScript infers the type of the onChange property as a union type of all the possible types of the arrow function parameters."

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about the way TS infers the type argument, probably only TS devs know it. Maybe it's trying to find the most specific type that fits, but I'm not sure. However there is a trick to tell typescript exactly from which place it should infer the type, which you may find helpful. Here's what it looks like:

```
// Add this weird type
type NoInfer<T> = T extends any ? T : T

type SomeComponentProps<T> = {
  onChange: (value: T) => void; 
  // Everywhere you don't want the generic to be inferred from, wrap it into this type
  availableValues: Array<NoInfer<T>>; 
  selectedValue: NoInfer<T> | null; 
  generateString: (value: NoInfer<T>) => string; 
}
```

Here only in `onChange` the `T` is not wrapped in `NoInfer`, so its value will be inferred only from there. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewTAvDA3sGMCGAuGAZxACcBLAOwHMBuGLGAIwIoFcBbRqEu4AX2CCAxggrEYAMySEYBAIIkSOMAB5ECAHyoYAbQaZs2fDABEOEwBp6hpgQCMDPlYOHjJxpeuHmMAEyPgAF1eUEhYADkEAEkKCW4VABUtNASYKAAPECgKABMZHAowGAB+GFSCBNDoGABlBHYoAGF6iFFskAAFEgQIQkTkjAZRRoALAqooAgAKADccABtWSbKASlQtGYQyHN4jObJ5nEZ5qAA1BaXCeUVlFUiYuJJ+jV2iKBOhLJzzxeX72PiSRgAB8YGx5vNXhMKNwcFkaqRKFRpnNfgR-o9+msUFpiORqLwBMAMq0SCAYCIxOS6g1muxWjCKOS0IkLBophBur0CDSmi02kyuj0+klsVpMETgLy6Qz2lMXDh9odjmcLlArpJpFYGIR3lBPlBvmqWKwIdrsMMxtRlrNjfAkCCwab5o68UjHWxONwxaYRu95ggAISWBjQ2HwxHUFE+mYAOhwMAA9ImOTglA0siQ1jMCOpBHwVoIgA).